# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined - jquery.js:7760

Tags: jquery

I have the following code (thanks to Mario for helping)

```
function toggle() {
    var noticeToggleElement = $(this);
    var newStatus = noticeToggleElement.val() === "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide";
    noticeToggleElement.val(newStatus);
    if (newStatus == "Show") {
        noticeToggleElement.css('overflow','hidden');
        noticeToggleElement.css('height','80px');
        $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','187px');
    }
    else {
        noticeToggleElement.css('overflow','visible');
        noticeToggleElement.css('height','100%');
        $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','100%');
    }
}
```

And HTML (with wrapper "notice-wrap"):

```
<div class="notice-title">
    Title
</div>

<div class="notice-content">
    Content text
</div>

<div class="notice-toggle" value="Hide" onclick="toggle()">
    <a href="#"><img src="../img/icon_rollout.png"></a>
</div>
```

And then i'm try to open the toggle i have this error:

**jquery.js:7760 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**

The error was appear after i add code above, but seems that the error on line 7760:

jQuery.fn.extend({
    val: function( value ) {
        var hooks, ret, isFunction,
            elem = this[0];

```
    if ( !arguments.length ) {
        if ( elem ) {
            hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

            if ( hooks && "get" in hooks && (ret = hooks.get( elem, "value" )) !== undefined ) {
                return ret;
            }
```

Where i made a mistake and how to correct it?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Are you sure the wrong code is here ? On what line is it raised ?

Comment: What is the context of this method? What is `this` referring to???  EDIT: if `this` is referring to `window`, then error is legit: `var noticeToggleElement = $(this);
    var newStatus = noticeToggleElement.val()` Here `val()` will throw this error

Comment: The error was appear after i add code above, but seems that the error on line 7760:

`       jQuery.fn.extend({
 val: function( value ) {
  var hooks, ret, isFunction,
   elem = this[0];

  if ( !arguments.length ) {
   if ( elem ) {
    hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

    if ( hooks && "get" in hooks && (ret = hooks.get( elem, "value" )) !== undefined ) {
     return ret;
    }`

Comment: Please post your html too.. OR if you can provide `fiddle` for this it would be great..

Comment: @SunilKumar: Better yet, a runnable Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button) right here on SO.

Comment: So ya, in your code `this` refers to `window` object...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder See here: https://jsfiddle.net/oLy3vtfg/   What's wrong then?

Comment: @A.Wolff: Yeah, just replicated it. Bizarre! That's an answer, you should post it as one. The solution (as it so often is) is *not to use `onxyz` attributes*! :-)

Comment: Post updated, added a line with error and HTML

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The thing is that `window` hasn't any nodeName property defined, so error is thrown on `elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()`. And even it fixes error, the problem of OP is somewhere else ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I see you may be calling the function toggle from any where in your script but in your function you didn't pass the reference for this keyword, as far as i think your function should be like this

```
function toggle(elmRef) {
var noticeToggleElement = $(elmRef);
var newStatus = noticeToggleElement.attr('data-value') === "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide";

noticeToggleElement.attr('data-value',newStatus);
if (newStatus == "Show") {
    noticeToggleElement.css('overflow','hidden');
    noticeToggleElement.css('height','80px');
    $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','187px');
}
else {
    noticeToggleElement.css('overflow','visible');
    noticeToggleElement.css('height','100%');
    $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','100%');
}
}
```

and when you call the function you will have to pass the reference of target element.

and your html calling will be like following.

```
<div class="notice-title">
 Title
</div>

<div class="notice-content">
 Content text
</div>

<div class="notice-toggle" data-value="Hide" onclick="toggle(this)">
 <a href="#"><img src="../img/icon_rollout.png"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: @MihailEfreetVigovskiy You have to pass `this` to inline click handler OR better, just use relevant unobstrusive js method to bind click event...

Comment: I have edited the answer please check, I have edited your function as well as a small changes in your html.

Comment: Still opening all items, and overflow now stay hidden, but thanks for you time and help!

Comment: But things are being happened now according your function logic, You can inspect element by firebug and check this, and as far as i think no error is coming now as you mentioned earlier,

Comment: Yep, no error, but i returned to my previous problem :)
Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try: (remove onclick from your html first)

```
$(document).on("click", ".notice-toggle", function(event){
  var noticeToggleElement = $(event.target);
  var newStatus = noticeToggleElement.attr('data-value') === "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide";
  noticeToggleElement.attr('data-value', newStatus);
  if (newStatus == "Show") {
    noticeToggleElement.css('overflow','hidden');
    noticeToggleElement.css('height','80px');
    $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','187px');
  }
  else {
    noticeToggleElement.css('overflow','visible');
    noticeToggleElement.css('height','100%');
    $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','100%');
  }
});
```

I'm pretty sure you're calling the wrong attribute `value` when you should be calling the attribute `data-value`:

`var newStatus = noticeToggleElement.val() === "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide";`

should be:

`var newStatus = noticeToggleElement.attr('data-value') === "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide";`

Comment: Unfortunately the same effect - opening all items

Comment: @MihailEfreetVigovskiy - okay, I've edited.. try again now?

Comment: The same...( HTML is '<div class="notice-toggle" data-value="Hide">', right?

Comment: It's a bit late where I am (Sydney) but I'll have another look at it in the morning.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Just checked again.. the code I've given appears to be working. See https://jsfiddle.net/czrL8cff/1/

Comment: Code is exactly the same, maybe i doing something wrong... or put wrong classes/styles

Comment: At least you now know the logic and syntax is correct.. now you just have to play around with the css until you get what you want.. it's a couple of steps further than you were :)

Comment: This classes assigned to toggle button (.notice-toggle), not for .notice-wrap and .notice-content (but i need change exactly this classes in each items)

Comment: To do that use `currentTarget` instead of `target` - https://jsfiddle.net/czrL8cff/4/

Comment: Oh okay.. so you want to target `.notice-content`? Why don't you use the `.notice-content` selector instead of  `noticeToggleElement`?

Comment: I use this:
`function toggle() {
    var newStatus = $('.notice-toggle').val() === "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide";
    $('.notice-toggle').val(newStatus);
    if (newStatus == "Show") {
        $("div.notice-content").css('overflow','hidden');
        $("div.notice-content").css('height','80px');
        $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','187px');
    }
    else {
        $("div.notice-content").css('overflow','visible');
        $("div.notice-content").css('height','100%');
        $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','100%');
    }
 }`

Comment: But in this case all elements are opened simultaneously